# PHP regex to split content following specific pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex in php to split the string to array.
The string is

```
#000000 | Black #ffffff | White #ff0000 | Red
```

there can or cannot be space between the character and

```
|
```

so the regex needs to work with

```
#000000|Black #ffffff|White #ff0000|Red
```

For the second type of string this works.

```
$str = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $str);
```

How can I modify it to work with the first and second both strings?

Edit: Final output needs to be

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => #000000 [1] => Black ) [1] => Array ( [0] => #ffffff [1] => White ) [2] => Array ( [0] => #ff0000 [1] => Red) )
```

Comment: What does your exact final output array look like?  I don't completely follow what you want as output here.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen , I've updated my question

Comment: I would first split on `#` - then you get pairs looking like `000000 | Black` - and then split these pairs on `|`.

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('~(#[a-fA-F0-9]+)\s*\|\s*(\S+)~', $s, $matches)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/34VrFv/1). `$matches` should contain the result you need.

Comment: on split by `|` the title of previous and code of next color are mixed up for ex. `Black #ffffff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend just generating a single flat map of color names to hexadecimal values.  Here is a way to do this with a single call to `preg_split`.  We can try splitting on the following regex pattern:

```
\s*\|\s*|\s+(?=#)
```

This says to split on either `\s*\|\s*` or `\s+(?=#)`, which is whitespace where what follows is the hash from a hexadecimal color literal.

```
$input = "#000000 | Black #ffffff | White #ff0000 | Red";
$array = preg_split("/\\s*\\|\\s*|\\s+(?=#)/", $input);

$map = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i+=2) {
    $map[$array[$i]] = $array[$i+1];
}

print_r($map);

Array ( [#000000] => Black [#ffffff] => White [#ff0000] => Red )
```

I did not give the exact output you expect, but I also don't see any reason to have any array of associate arrays.  If you really need that, then use this code:

```
$input = "#000000 | Black #ffffff | White #ff0000 | Red";
$array = preg_split("/\s*\|\s*|\s+(?=#)/", $input);

$output = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i+=2) {
    $map = array();
    $map[$array[$i]] = $array[$i+1];
    $output[count($output)] = $map;
}

print_r($output);

Array ( [0] => Array ( [#000000] => Black ) [1] => Array ( [#ffffff] => White )
    [2] => Array ( [#ff0000] => Red ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works for `$input = "#000000 | Black #ffffff | White #ff0000 | Red";` but not for `$input = "#000000 | Black #ffffff | White #ff0000 | Red";`

Comment: Your comment makes no sense because both `$input` are the same.  Please provide a case where my code does not work.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typing mistake, this works for $input = "#000000 | Black #ffffff | White #ff0000 | Red"; but not for $input = "#000000|Black #ffffff|White #ff0000|Red"; in second one, there no space between last character of color code and `|`

Comment: @geekgeek I fixed it.  Small change needed to the pattern used to split.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split two times first using this regex,

```
'/ (?=#)/'
```

and then using this regex,

```
'/\s*\|\s*/'
```

Here is a php code,

```
$str = "#000000|Black #ffffff|White #ff0000|Red";
$str = preg_split('/ (?=#)/', $str);
for ($i = 0;$i<sizeOf($str);$i++) {
    $str[$i] = preg_split('/\s*\|\s*/', $str[$i]);
}
print_r($str);
```

This gives following output,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #000000
            [1] => Black
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => #ffffff
            [1] => White
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => #ff0000
            [1] => Red
        )

)
```

For this string "#ff0000|#ff0000" it gives following output, which is what you want.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #ff0000
            [1] => #ff0000
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you try my codes? I think this exactly gives the output as you want in your post.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this don't work if there # in title, for example if `$str = #ff0000|#ff0000`, for this case the array should be `$result[0][0] = #ff0000 and $result[0][1] = #ff0000;`

Comment: I think it is giving you your expected output. I've updated my answer to include the new input string you mentioned.